# setAttribute doesn't work on ie any workaround?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code.Its working fine on firefox

```
<script language="JavaScript"type="text/javascript">
 window.onload=function createDiv()
    { 
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id','errorMessage');
    div.setAttribute('class','blockMessage');
    var text = document.createTextNode('TO close the message click on cancel');
    var closeText=document.createElement('span');
    closeText.setAttribute('id','close');
    closeText.setAttribute('onclick','destroyObject()');
    var text1=document.createTextNode('Close');
    closeText.appendChild(text1);
    div.appendChild(text);
    div.appendChild(closeText);

document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);

//body.appendChild(div);
    }
 function destroyObject(){
    var getId=document.getElementById('errorMessage');
    getId.remove(getId);
 }

    </script>
```

Comment: you could start by taking a look at your console and tearing your code down until you find out where it gets stuck.

Comment: This might helps for workaround: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html

Comment: @Sudhir you should put that in an answer...

Comment: Please note that you should move the onclick to the div and not the text node + in the `destroyObject()` function, use `getId.parentNode.removeChild( getId );`

Comment: @Yaniro,BOLDEWYN,SUDHIR,JOSEPH THNX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As workaround, you could add some more code if its IE, like:

```
//for class
div.className = "your_class_name";
//for onclick
div.onclick = function() {destroyObject();}; // for IE
```

See [here](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html) for more

Answer (score 1):

For old versions of IE (6/7) use can use properties instead of attributes:

```
div.id = 'errorMessage';
div.className = 'blockMessage';
closeText.onclick = destroyObject;
```